# How to get a quotes string in R?

Tags: r, string, quotes

I have a string variable. For example `var = "aaa bbb ccc"`. Using the some function (that I don't know) I need to get the following string `var = "aaa", "bbb", "ccc"`.

I know there is the `scan` function but I can't have the needed configuration of commas and quotes.

Please help me find the function I'm searching.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you need a single strng as output

Comment: `strsplit("aaa bbb ccc", "\\s+")`

Comment: Do you need a single string that has embedded quotes, or a vector of three strings?

Comment: @r2evans it gives commas inside the quotes, but I need them to be outside.

Comment: Huh? `strsplit` gives no commas at all.

Comment: @r2evans Oh! Sorry! You rigth. But I need the commas.

Comment: Does akrun's answer work for you?

Comment: @r2evans It doesn't because he asked, but not suggested a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `gsub`

```
gsub("(\\w+) ", '"\\1",', var)
```

---

Or another option is `dQuote`

```
toString(dQuote(scan(text = var, what =""), FALSE))
```

For single quote, use `sQuote`, and the quote surrounding the whole string wouldn't have an effect

```
cat(toString(sQuote(scan(text = var, what ="", quiet = TRUE), FALSE)))
#'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need something another configuration. I want to have just the following statement `var = 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'` in order to paste into sql statement like this `case when var1 in (var) then 1 else 0 end`. The suggested way is not applicable in this sense, unfortunately.

Comment: Not clear about the structure you wanted.  Is it a single string or multiple string

Comment: it's a single string

Comment: my output is also a single. string for both solutions.  If you need single quote, then use `sQuote` instead of `dQuote` i.d. `toString(sQuote(scan(text = var, what =""), FALSE))`